# Cakephp 403 error not displaying custom page

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, http-status-code-403

I receive the standard apache 403 error page when navigating to places in mysite.com/img which translates to app/webroot/img.

I am using Cakephp 2.x and have setup the custom error400.ctp which works correctly for 404 errors as far as I have tested.

Is this an htaccess problem that is not letting cakephp handle the error? How do I get the error400.ctp page to show without hardcoding the path in .htaccess?

Here is my app/webroot .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should have 3 htaccess files. One in / (root), one in /app, and one in /app/webroot. Paste in your code from all 3, and update your question to mention any modifications you've added to Cake's default htaccess files.

Comment: This is by design, things in app/webroot are not handled by CakePHP.

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses! I will carry on with more important things than 403 errors.

Answer (score 2):

In your AppController write the following code.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if($this->name == 'CakeError'){
        $this->layout = 'error400';
    }
}
```

This will work for all the cake errors.

Comment: same problem having with `cakephp 3.6` any idea how to solve and display `error403.ctp` page for forbidden error

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi You can check for errors in above mentioned `beforeFilter()` method